# Wordpress how to retrieve aguments from filter

Tags: wordpress, filter, arguments

lets say this filter for example:

```
apply_filters( 'wp_generate_attachment_metadata', $metadata, $attachment_id );
```

I will hook on it like this:

```
function my_func($wut,$huh){
    //...my code...
}
add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata', 'my_func' );
```

How can I access the `$metadata` and `$attachment_id` from the initial apply_filter call in my function?

Comment: from wp documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/ . function my_func($wut,$huh){
    //...my code...
}
add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata', 'my_func', 10, 2 );

Comment: ah thank you I get it now, I must put that 4th argument to allow a second parameter otherwise its locked at 1! That works thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Samvel for your comment, that totally works.

As seen on this page: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/ I needed to add that 4th argument in my add_filter and set it to 2 to allow a second argument to pass in, otherwise it was locked at 1. Thats why I couldnt retrieve that second argument!